# How to add a class to a whole table row in angular

Tags: css, angular

table with a tr in it. Now I would like if you click on that table row the backgroundcolor changes. Why I want this is because I am using a tree table to open up this table row. And I would like it if you click on this table row that the background color of the whole row changes. Now if I close this table row (by clicking on it again) I would like that the backgroundcolor goes back to normal

```
<ng-template pTemplate="header">
            <tr>
                <th>Bedrijsnaam</th>
                <th>Bedrijfstype</th>
                <th>Status</th>
                <th>Bank</th>
            </tr>
        </ng-template>
```

This is the tr I am talking about. I tried using `ng-class` but without any luck. Does someone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `(click)` and `[ngClass]` on the `tr`.

Ex :

```
   <tr (click)="toggleClass()" [ngClass]="{active: className}">
      ....
    </tr>
```

### in ts

let className = "";

```
toggleClass(){
 if(this.className === "active"){
    this.className = "" 
}else{
   this.className = "active";
 }
}
```

### in csss

```
.active{
   background-color: yellow;
 }
```

> Note this implemenation is for one tr you may need to attach this `className` for each row.

Answer (score 0):

This another solution and you don't need to create a property in the component

```
<tr #tr (click)="tr.classList.toggle('active')" >
      ....
</tr>
```

[**demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4zbe5n)

Answer (score 0):

**Table.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-table',
  templateUrl: './table.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./table.component.css']
})
export class TableComponent {
  tableRowClicked = false;

  toggleTableRowClicked() {
    this.tableRowClicked = !this.tableRowClicked;
  }
}
```

- Create an instance variable `tableRowClicked` to manage whether the table row has been clicked or not.
- Create a toggle function to toggle the variable true or false.

**Table.component.html**

```
<div>
  <table>
    <tr (click)="toggleTableRowClicked()" [class.table__row--clicked]="tableRowClicked">
      <th>Bedrijsnaam</th>
      <th>Bedrijfstype</th>
      <th>Status</th>
      <th>Bank</th>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

- Invoke the toggle function using the click handler on the `<tr>`
- Apply the `table__row--clicked` class when `tableRowClicked=true`

**Table.component.css**

```
.table {
  &__row {
    &--clicked {
      background-color: red;
    }
  }
}
```

- CSS to make the `background-color: red;` when the `tableRowClicked = true`